# I don't see SSH disconnect events with `journalctl -u sshd`

Tags: ssh, systemd, journalctl

I want to monitor SSH sessions, including login and logout events. When I run `journalctl` without any flags, I see both login events like:

```
Accepted publickey for root from 192.168.1.24 port 56464
```

and logout events like:

```
Disconnected from user root 192.168.1.24 port 56464
```

But when I want to reduce the output and filter only the `sshd` events I run `journalctl -u sshd`. In this case I see only the `Accepted publickey` events, but not the `Disconnected from user` events.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Instead of `journalctl -u sshd` you should use `journalctl -t sshd`.

To figure out that, I ran `journalctl -o json-pretty` and analyzed login and logout events. The login events have `"_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "sshd.service"` in their JSON output, so they show up when you specify the unit with `-u sshd`. But the logout events have `"_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "session-27.scope"`, and that's why they are not shown for `-u sshd`. Of course, the session number is different for each SSH session.

What *is* common for both logout and login events is `"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "sshd"` which means we have to use the `-t` flag (or long-form `--identifier`) to specify the identifier.

This is on Fedora and RHEL. I haven't tested it on Debian/Ubuntu yet. Please comment if it's different there.

I hope this will help somebody.